# How ADT message changes when final set of codes are added to a patient record?

Tags: hl7-v2

We receive ADT messages and want to know if all billing diagnosis and procedure codes are available in ADT. My understanding is when a patient is admitted ADT admit message will have diagnosis codes with diagnosis type 'A' ( Admitting) and then when the patient is discharged or even during patient stay, the codes will say diagnosis type as 'W'(Working). And then when final coding will take place after discharge, diagnosis type for all codes will change to 'F' (Final).

1. Is my understanding correct where we can know that ADT record has all final codes if type for all the codes reflect 'F' ?
2. Usually after a discharge (A03 ADT message), how many approx updates I might receive before billing starts to cross over and all codes are final ?

Thanks